# dropdown option for multiple marker icons with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, drop-down-menu

I.m confusing to change my custom icon maps with option value. So please help me with your comments. :D

Here's the option value

```
      <select name='type' id='type' onChange='document.getElementById("customicon").value="this.value"'>
  <option<?php if($place['type'] == "sekolahremaja") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Sekolah Remaja</option>
  <option<?php if($place['type'] == "jalanremaja") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Jalan Remaja</option>
  <option<?php if($place['type'] == "komunitas") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Komunitas</option>
  <option<?php if($place['type'] == "screening") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Screening</option>
  <option<?php if($place['type'] == "lembaga") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Lembaga</option>
  <option<?php if($place['type'] == "personal") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Personal</option>
  <option<?php if($place['type'] == "foto") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Foto</option>
        </select>
```

and here's my javascript code

```
var customicon = {
    "sekolahremaja" : "sekolahremaja",
    "jalanremaja" : "jalanremaja",
    "komunitas" : "komunitas",
    "screening" : "screening",
    "lembaga" : "lembaga",
    "personal" : "personal",
    "events" : "events",
    };
var markerImage = "../images/icons/"+customicon+".png";

          <?php if ($_GET['place_id']){?>
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$place['lat']?>,<?=$place['lng']?>),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            draggable: true,
            icon: markerImage
          });
```

Comment: maybe you need something like `var markerImage = "../images/icons/"+customicon[keyOfSelectedOption]+".png";` since the customicon is JSON data. anyway what is #customicon?

Comment: #customicon is my variable for option value, i don't know if it's wrong. I don't know how to use javascript -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this one

```
<select name='type' id='type' onChange="changeImage(this.value)">
  <option value="sekolahremaja" <?php if($place['type'] == "sekolahremaja") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Sekolah Remaja</option>
  <option value="jalanremaja" <?php if($place['type'] == "jalanremaja") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Jalan Remaja</option>
  <option value="komunitas" <?php if($place['type'] == "komunitas") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Komunitas</option>
  <option value="screening" <?php if($place['type'] == "screening") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Screening</option>
  <option value="lembaga" <?php if($place['type'] == "lembaga") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Lembaga</option>
  <option value="personal" <?php if($place['type'] == "personal") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Personal</option>
  <option value="foto" <?php if($place['type'] == "foto") {?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>>Foto</option>
        </select>
```

your javascript like the follwing

```
var markerImage='';
function changeImage(value)
{
  markerImage = "../images/icons/"+customicon.value+".png";
}
```

as customicon is object

now `markerImage` have the url of image which you want show as icon of marker

also check the `position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$place['lat']?>,<?=$place['lng']?>)`
here you need to convert `lat` and `lng` into number like following

```
 position: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(<?=$place['lat']?>),Number(<?=$place['lng']?>))
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is what you looking for.

```
<select name='type' id='type' onchange='changeMarker(this.value)'>
  <option value="sekolahremaja">Sekolah Remaja</option>
  ...
  <option value="foto">Foto</option>
</select>
```

the javascript stuff

```
function changeMarker(v){
  var customicon = {
    "sekolahremaja" : "sekolahremaja",
    "jalanremaja" : "jalanremaja",
    "komunitas" : "komunitas",
    "screening" : "screening",
    "lembaga" : "lembaga",
    "personal" : "personal",
    "events" : "events",
    };
  var markerImage = "../images/icons/"+customicon[v]+".png";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$place['lat']?>,<?=$place['lng']?>),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            draggable: true,
            icon: markerImage
          });
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it still does't work. :( i thought i've problem with another script, but thank you verymuch :) i'll keep your code on my notes. : )